# How to speed up the script in Google tables?

Tags: javascript

There is a table in which there are many sheets. Some of the cells are filled with values, some with formulas. It is required to block cells with formulas from changes. They need to be available for changes only to a limited number of users. I managed to write this script, but it doesn't work fast. Are there any ways to speed it up?

```
function myFunction2() {
const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
 
for(const sheeto of sheets) { //проводим перебор всех листов
 
 var ss1 = sheeto.getName();
 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(ss1);
 var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE); 
 for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) { //удаляем имеющиеся блокировки при наличии
   var protection = protections[i];
   if (protection.canEdit()) {
     protection.remove();
   }
 }
 var arr2 = ss.getDataRange().getFormulas();
 var numRows = arr2.length-1;
 var numCols = arr2[0].length-1;
 for (var i = 0; i <= numCols; ++i) {
   for (var y = 0; y <= numRows; ++y) {
     if (arr2[y][i]!="") { //блокируем все с формулами
       var range = ss.getRange(y+1,i+1);
       var protection = range.protect().setDescription('автозащита');
       var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
       protection.addEditor(me);
       
       protection.addEditor('пользователь1');
       protection.addEditor('пользователь2');
       protection.addEditor('пользователь3');
       protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
       if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
         protection.setDomainEdit(false);

       }
     }
   }
 }
}
}
```

I tried to use named ranges or assign blocking ranges directly in the protections array, but in this case my code gave errors and did not work fully.

Answer (score 0):

in general found to change the approach. I block not separately ranges, but the whole sheet. Cells without a formula, which should be increased to changes, are stored in an array. And I pass this array to the listing block as exclusion ranges. With this approach, it turns out much faster.

```
function myFunction2() {
const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  
for(const sheeto of sheets) {
  
  var ss1 = sheeto.getName();
  if  (ss1!="Лист1"  ) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(ss1);
  

  var arr2 = ss.getDataRange().getFormulas();
  

  var numRows = arr2.length-1;
  var numCols = arr2[0].length-1;

var Range1 = new Array(0);
var Range2 = new Array(0);
var Range3 = new Array(1);
vyh: {
  for (var i = 3; i <= numRows; ++i) {
    for (var y = 3; y <= numCols; ++y) {
      if (arr2[i][y]!="") {
        
        
       

      }
      else{
        yy=y+1
        ii=i+1
        Range1.length=Range1.length+1
        Range1[Range1.length-1]=yy 
        Range2.length=Range2.length+1
        Range2[Range2.length-1]=ii 

      }  
    }
  }

}

Range3[0]=col2A1(Range1[0]) + Range2[0]
ii=1
f=0
for (var i = 1; i <= Range1.length-1; ++i){

  if (Range2[i]==Range2[i-1] && Range1[i-1]==Range1[i]-1) {
    if (f==0) {
    Range3[ii-1] = Range3[ii-1] + ":" + col2A1(Range1[i]) + Range2[i]
    f=1
    }
    else{
      Range3[ii-1]=Range3[ii-1].slice(0, Range3[ii-1].indexOf(":")) + ":" + col2A1(Range1[i]) + Range2[i]
      
    }
  }
  else {
    Range3[ii]=col2A1(Range1[i]) + Range2[i]
    ii=ii+1
    f=0

  }

 }



var protection = ss.protect().setDescription('автозащита листа');

var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
protection.addEditor(me);

protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
  protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}
var protection = ss.protect();

var unprotected = protection.getUnprotectedRanges();

 for (var i = 0; i <= Range3.length-1; ++i){
unprotected.push(ss.getRange(Range3[i]));
protection.setUnprotectedRanges(unprotected);


 }
 }
}
}  


function col2A1(col){
  let result = "";
  let base = 27;
  while(col>0){    
    let newLetter = String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0)+(col-1)%(base-1));  
    result=newLetter + result;
    col = (col - col%base) / base;
  };
  return result;
};
```